# Form keeps refreshing

Tags: jquery, forms

I'm playing around with some existing code and want to add some jQuery to make it a little modern. Here is my code:

```
<form stuff>
<div class="inputContainer">
        <input placeholder="Name" type="text" name="FullName" id="FullName" class="cat_textbox" maxlength="255" />
    </div>
<!--Other stuff and submit-->
</form>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('#FullName').keyup(function(e) {
        var fullName = $(this).val();
        if(fullName.length > 5){
            alert("greater than 5");
        }
        else{
            var $toAppend = $(' div ')
                .addClass(' result ')
                .html('Length is not greater than 5');
            $toAppend.after(this);


        }
    });

});

</script>
```

When I try to append, the page refreshes. Looking at inspect element, there is nothing there! Can't figure it out. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want:

```
var $toAppend = $('<div>')
```

not

```
var $toAppend = $(' div ')
```

The first one makes a new `<div>`; the second selects any and all existing `<div>`s on the page, which you then `after(this)`, moving/copying (?) them.

Comment: I'm such an idiot! Can't believe I forgot the tag.. Thank you so much! I also changed my syntax from after to

$(this).parent().append($toAppend);

Comment: Are you sure this works? It looks to me like your `after()` is incorrect - your appending `this` to `$toAppend`

Comment: @Rowenia is correct in that you need to add the greater than and less than, but I don't think it solves the question of the refresh.  You need to change the last line: http://jsfiddle.net/Q3n3v/.  If you want to keep it the way you have it, you'll need to use [`insertAfter()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/) instead of `after()`.

Comment: will give it a shot! Still new to all this jQuery. I love it. Thanks heaps for your comments!